# How can I generate a custom script with Sprockets, not part of the normal Rails asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

In Rails, I want to generate some JavaScript dynamically and upload it to S3. First of course I need to generate it. I need something like:

Sprockets.generateFile("assets/application.js", {name: "John", age: 35})

Which would generate a string like:

```
(function() {
  var data = {name: "John", age: 35};
  function thisComesFromMyAssets() {
    ...
  }
 function moreStuff() {
 }
})()
```

Then I can take that string and upload it to S3.

I'm struggling reading the Sprockets and asset pipeline docs to figure out how to actually do this. Does someone more familiar know how?

Comment: there are better ways to push user-data into js. why exactly do you need to generate stuff upfront and load it from s3?

Answer (score 0):

At first make sure it's asset pipeline that you want to use for this task:

1. You can pass user-data to js via rendering inline js in html templates that are served to that user or use a gem like "gon" and only keep common code in compiled js
2. Also before all the troubles with generating+uploading+serving did you try serving these files dynamically like regular rails actions? JS is just text and is easily rendered via ERB (action_name.js.erb)
3. If your task is in making many standalone js-files with user data - better do it outside of asset pipeline (rake/activejob/PORO services), because in this case these files do not relate so directly to your deploys. You also should handle versioning, because users can have stale data.
4. Finally if task is really in making a single file with some semi-dynamic data - asset pipeline will handle `finename.js.erb`, but keep in mind that it is going to be compiled on deploy leading to corresponding data age concerns

Comment: It's going to be part of a rake task.